# How to close runtime permission dialog programmatically?

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

We need to implement a scenario where we have to close runtime permission dialog with Denial after 5 seconds of inactivity of user.

Steps:

1. User clicks the Save button
2. Permission dialog shown.
3. If user doesn't click accept/deny in 5 seconds

Expected Result: Dialog should be closed with deny as selected option.

Any help would be appreciated.

Also please let me know that if this is even possible to do so or not ?

Comment: I'm kinda curious, why would this ever be a good idea from a user experience standpoint? What if I am not looking at the screen? What if I am a slow reader?????

Comment: Everything can be done. But why this? I didn't like what you are doing :)

Comment: Can anyone please let me know if it's even possible or not.

And this is for one of my project not product. So i have been asked to implement this way and I have to implement it or tell the client that its not possible.

Comment: @PankajKumar can you please share your thoughts on my latest comment ?

Comment: @ZUNJAE can you please share your thoughts on my latest comment ?

Comment: @AsifBanarasDhamial No, that is not possible. That UI-element (that seems an activity who controls all these permission handling) does not belongs to your application so you do not have control.

Comment: Asif, please do NOT do this. It's a very bad idea and shows that you aren't a caring programmer.

Comment: @ZUNJAE I dont really want to do this and I do care about these stuff as well :). Thanks for your replies guys. Really appreciated.

Comment: @Asif Banaras Dhamial did you get the solution.I also facing the same problem.Can you give me the solution please.

Comment: @VinojVetha I didn't find any solution to this problem other than convincing the client

Comment: @AsifBanarasDhamial Thank you.Do you have any reference link for convincing the client ?

Comment: @VinojVetha I did convinced client by saying that it is a technical limitation and cant be handled other than OS itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a valid edge case, as explained below.

### The solution

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));
```

### Why close the permission dialog?

Let's say the user starts your app and the permission dialog is immediately shown, e.g. from a fragment. Then the user switches to another app from which a new intent is sent to your app, e.g. `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`. Then you might want to change/rearrange the UI before showing the permission dialog:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    if (isShowingPermissionDialog() {
        // Handle this intent after permisson dialog is dismissed!
        mPendingIntent = intent;
    } else {
        // This could interfere with the expected permission
        // callback of the active fragment etc.
        changeActiveFragment();
    }
}
```

Or, if you instead want to explicitly close the permission dialog:

```
private void closeSystemDialogs() {
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));
}

protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    closeSystemDialogs();

    changeActiveFragment();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, they deprecated ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS in Android 12.