# How to dismiss permissions dialog programmatically?

Tags: android, permissions, dialog

When the user pauses/closes the screen, while a permissions prompt dialog is active, the dialog persists over the locked screen when the user tries to use the phone again (and needs to make a choice for the dialog to go away).

Although a detail, it does not look very nice, and I would like to dismiss that prompt dialog in `onPause()`. How can I do that? Perhaps I should programmatically choose to deny permissions in `onPause()` instead?

Comment: same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51102456/how-to-close-runtime-permission-dialog-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

From another point of view, it is also not very nice that user can't continue his task when returning to your app.
So, persistent dialog is a feature and the point is that user decides when to deny or accept permissions - it's the best to not do anything programmatically

Comment: That is true. I would not mind if the permission dialog persisted behind the locked screen (i.e. it appeared after I unlocked the phone again and resuming the app).

Comment: @George did you find any way to close the permission alert in Android programatically ?